# Wait for query to fetch Firestore data before continue

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to fetch the user/author of the article into a computed property. But this never happens, below code would print 1, 2, 4.

```
struct Article {
    private let database = Firestore.firestore()

    var authorId: String
    var message: String

    var author: User? {

        print(1)
        var fetchedAuthor: User?
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

        print(2)
        database.collection("users").document(authorId).getDocument { (document, error) in

            print(3)
            guard let user = document.flatMap({User(dictionary: $0.data())}) else {
                print("Could not get author: \(error.debugDescription)")
                semaphore.signal()
                return
            }

            fetchedAuthor = user
            semaphore.signal()
        }

        print(4)

        semaphore.wait()
        print(5)
        return fetchedAuthor
    }
}
```

Comment: Having an asynchronous call inside a computed `var` is not a good idea. Any working version of this code will, every time you call the `author` variable, make a network request and freeze the main thread until it's done. Generally, you want an asynchronous _function_ with a _completion block_ ie `func fetchAuthor(completion: (User?, Error?) -> Void)`, which you call once and assign the result to a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will give it a try

Comment: First of all, **computed properties** aren't exact replacement of **functions**. Then, even if you don't make any network request but have asynchronous retrieval mechanisms, you **shouldn't wrap those with computed properties**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding pseudo/ sample code to the comment by @Connor, since I just went through this.

```
extension User {
  static func getBy(documentID id: String, completion: @escaping (User)->()) {
    database.collection("users").document(id).getDocument { (document, error) in
        guard let user = document.flatMap({User(dictionary: $0.data())}) else {
            print("Could not get author: \(error.debugDescription)")
            return
        }
        completion(user)
  }
}
```

Then in your Article struct:

```
struct Article {
  ....
  init(){
    ....
    // Get the user
    User.getBy(documentID: self.userID) { user in
      self.author = user
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I went with so I'm gonna mark it as accepted - Although this will return a "Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter" when using struct as a model object.

Answer (score 0):

```
semaphore.wait() //is for requesting the resource(semaphore)
semaphore.singal() //is for releasing the resource(semaphore)
```

Change code as per below.

```
var author: User? {

        print(1)
        var fetchedAuthor: User?
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

        print(2)
        database.collection("users").document(authorId).getDocument { (document, error) in
            semaphore.wait()
            print(3)
            guard let user = document.flatMap({User(dictionary: $0.data())}) else {
                print("Could not get author: \(error.debugDescription)")
                return
            }

            fetchedAuthor = user
            semaphore.signal()
        }

        print(4)
        print(5)
        return fetchedAuthor
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this will print out 1245 and then 3. So it just goes straight to the return

Comment: Same. This will print 1245 nil 3

Comment: link for reference: https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/a-quick-look-at-semaphores-6b7b85233ddb

Comment: No, same problem. Think I would try out @connor's answer, thanks for the help, really appreciate it!